# Combine multiple MySql queries into a single query using date condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named users.

```
id   name date       cdate           c  a   b
1     rz  42121221  42121221         0  1   0
2     an  12122111  42121221         0  0   1
3     cb  22121221  42121221         1  1   1   
4     ss  3321221   42121221         1  0   0
```

I have to select the values between two dates, and then i have to find the count using this statement.

```
 SELECT COALESCE(SUM(IF(c=1 AND a=0 AND b=1  ,  1, 0)),0) AS ACTIVE
   WHERE DATE BETWEEN 'DATE 1' AND 'DATE 2',
 COALESCE(SUM(IF(c=0 AND a=0 AND b=1  ,  1, 0)),0) AS INC
   WHERE cdate BETWEEN 'DATE 1' AND 'DATE 2'
 FROM users where dealer id='2'
```

This query is not working.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `DATE ` BETWEEN 'DATE 1' AND 'DATE 2',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your query, properly formatted. You can only have one WHERE clause per SELECT statement, and the FROM clause goes after the SELECT clause and before the WHERE clause.

```
 SELECT SUM(IF(c=1 AND a=0 AND b=1 AND DATE BETWEEN 'DATE 1' AND 'DATE 2', 1, 0)) AS ACTIVE,
   SUM(IF(c=0 AND a=0 AND b=1 AND cdate BETWEEN 'DATE 1' AND 'DATE 2', 1, 0)) AS INC
 FROM users
 WHERE DATE BETWEEN 'DATE 1' AND 'DATE 2'
   OR cdate BETWEEN 'DATE 1' AND 'DATE 2'
```

I copied your date comparisons into the IF statements.

Also, I removed the COALESCE clause because it was redundant in this case. SUM always returns a value.

I put the columns together, separated by a comma, after the SELECT clause.

You may wish to remove the WHERE clause now, depending on what you're trying to do.

I'm also suspicious of `cdate BETWEEN 'DATE 1' AND 'DATE 2'`. If cdate is a DATETIME column, you'll want to put in properly formatted dates in the constants. If DATE 1 and DATE 2 are column names, then you'll need back ticks, not single quotes, like this:

```
cdate BETWEEN `DATE 1` AND `DATE 2`
```

You should consider reading the documentation on the [SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: so i have two use two select staemet?

Comment: @coolboy, no, take a look at my query above. You can use one SELECT statement and separate the columns with a comma. There are many good examples in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: what about the date condition for active ?

Comment: @coolboy, Doh! I didn't see that the date condition was different. You'll have to move them into the IF clause also. Just a moment, while I update my answer.

Comment: okay thanku so much i need to add one more condition where id='2'

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like this to achieve your need in one query :

Give it a try :

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(IF(u1.c=1 AND u1.a=0 AND u1.b=1, 1, 0)),0) AS ACTIVE,
COALESCE(SUM(IF(u2.c=0 AND u2.a=0 AND u2.b=1, 1, 0)),0) AS INC
from user u1
left outer join user u2 on u1.row_id = u2.row_id
where u1.DATE BETWEEN 'DATE 1' AND 'DATE 2' and
u2.cdate BETWEEN 'DATE 1' AND 'DATE 2'
```